# Need to query "order date" larger than "filled date" any suggestions?

Tags: date, compare

I have a query with over 500,000 rows of data in the output. I need to filter the criteria down so that I am comparing column "order date" to column "filled date". I want to find all orders with a filled date sooner than an order date (yes, that sounds backwards). Is there an easy way to query this in design view? I am not very good with SQL.

Comment: What database are you using? What designer are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the SQL to look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE filled_date < order_date
```

How to do it in the designer depends on which designer you are using.

Comment: your logic is backwards, however i suspect a badly worded question.

Comment: @Andrew Bullock: Yes it's backwards - I *think* that's what she wanted.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, the logic is backwards intentionally. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select *
from [orders]
where [filled date] > [order date]
```

obviously use your field and table names